# Angular - official docs *ngFor count demo not working

Tags: angular

I've upgraded to Angular 4 and tested their demo regarding the `*ngFor` functionalities (available here: http://angularjs.blogspot.si/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html), which are:

```
<div *ngIf="userList | async as users; else loading">
  <user-profile *ngFor="let user of users; count as count" [user]="user">
  </user-profile>
 <div>{{count}} total users</div>
</div>
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
```

The `count` part just doesn't work like that I guess. I'm not sure if that's part of Angular 4 or 2, but regardless, it doesn't work. Here's my example on plnkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/IOX558pMkRqCxpSzcTVS?p=preview

As you can see the other parts work fine, but `count` is empty. This happens locally as well, it's not a plnkr bug I suppose.

Comment: It's Angular4 only

Comment: I am using Angular 4, right? Since the `else loading` part works, it's probably all good on plnkr. And besides, I've upgraded to Angular 4 locally and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This variable is only available inside the element where you apply `*ngFor`

For example

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let user of users;  let count=count">
  <user-profile  [user]="user"></user-profile>
  <div>{{count}} total users</div>
</ng-container>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JMmAQ5O1Fv0wCsTbLFO8)

Comment: I managed to get that working too; to use `count` inside the `ngFor`. But that's not the example from the official docs. So I'm wondering is that a bug in their documentation or am I not doing something right?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me

Comment: yeah, `count as count` works if used inside `*ngFor`, but not outside as used in the docs. I suppose it's a bug in the docs...

Comment: That is true, but it was posted by a Google employee so I take it as "official"